# My python game is not responding when I run it

Tags: python

so I have been trying to make this game in python using only standard libraries because I don't know how to link libraries (I am an absolute beginner) but whenever I run the program, it doesn't respond. This is the code:

```
import turtle
import random
import math
import time
import os

play = True

#window
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("#4287f5")
window.title("Box Grab!")

#border
outer = turtle.Turtle()
outer.speed(0)
outer.color("#000000","#000000")
outer.up()
outer.goto(250, 250)
outer.down
outer.begin_fill()
for i in range(4):
    outer.rt(90)
    outer.fd(500)
outer.ht()

#boxes
box1 = turtle.Turtle()
box2 = turtle.Turtle()
box3 = turtle.Turtle()
box4 = turtle.Turtle()
box5 = turtle.Turtle()
box6 = turtle.Turtle()

box1n = 2
box2n = 2
box3n = 2
box4n = 2
box5n = 2
box6n = 2

box1.penup()
box1.speed(0)
box1.color("darkorange")
box1.shape("square")

box2.penup()
box2.speed(0)
box2.color("darkorange")
box2.shape("square")

box3.penup()
box3.speed(0)
box3.color("darkorange")
box3.shape("square")

box4.penup()
box4.speed(0)
box4.color("darkorange")
box4.shape("square")

box5.penup()
box5.speed(0)
box5.color("darkorange")
box5.shape("square")

box6.penup()
box6.speed(0)
box6.color("darkorange")
box6.shape("square")

box1.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
box2.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
box3.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
box4.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
box5.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
box6.setpos(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))

#player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.penup()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("circle")

#defining movement
def down():
    player.setheading(270)
    player.forward(20)
def right():
    player.setheading(0)
    player.forward(20)
def left():
    player.setheading(180)
    player.forward(20)
def up():
    player.setheading(90)
    player.forward(20)

#collision
def isCollision(t1, t2):
           d = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor()-t2.xcor(),2) + math.pow(t1.ycor()-t2.ycor(),2))
           if d < 20:
               return True
           else:
               return False

if isCollision(player, box1):
    box1.hideturtle()
    box1n - 1
if isCollision(player, box2):
    box2.hideturtle()
    box2n - 1
if isCollision(player, box3):
    box3.hideturtle()
    box3n - 1
if isCollision(player, box4):
    box4.hideturtle()
    box4n - 1
if isCollision(player, box5):
    box5.hideturtle()
    box5n - 1
if isCollision(player, box6):
    box6.hideturtle()
    box6n - 1

#movement
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(up,"w")
turtle.onkey(down,"s")
turtle.onkey(right,"d")
turtle.onkey(left,"a")

#time
def mainTime():
    x = 60
    for i in range(60 + 1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(formatTime(x))
        x -= 1
def formatTime(x):
    minutes = int(x / 60)
    seconds_rem = int(x % 60)
    if (seconds_rem < 10):
        return(str(minutes) + ":0" + str(seconds_rem))
    else:
        return(str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds_rem))
    if x == 0:
        play = false

mainTime()

#score
def score():
    score = 0
    for s in range(60):
        t = 60
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
    if box1 or box2 or box3 or box4 or box5 or box6 == 1:
        score = score + (seconds_rem * 100)
score()

#game over
if play == false:
    print("GAME OVER. ")
    restart = input("RESTART? Y/N")
    if restart == "y":
        os.system('python "C:\\Users\\lyons\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Projects\\failing to make a game.py"')
```

Also, when it used to work, the boxes wouldn't dissapear after the player hit them. How do I fix this?

Comment: did you try to put turtle.mainloop()  or turtle.done() somewhere in your code? i am not familiar with turtle module, but in general windowed module required to fire some kind of  event loop,  you can do more research on the mainloop() and done() call before trying.

Comment: Well you should write a main loop where you call all your functions, then you can read your code much better. Right now main_time() gets called and just runs until the loop is finished so you dont register any user input because your stuck in that loop.

Comment: another thing: with a main function you can just call main() to run the program and restart it with calling main() again instead of entering a console command

Comment: Thanks for that!